# Is there a query to get all the columns between 2 columns?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with >50 columns. I have the names of two columns. However, I would like to sum the values of these 2 columns as well as all the columns between them (>50). It seems very impractical to type all the column names in a sum statement. Is there a query for this? I am using SQL Impala by the way.

Comment: Yes, it's impractical to type them all. But that's the price to pay when you decide against normalizing your database model.

Comment: A relational database has no concept of column order within a table - so unless you have some mechanism to sort them (e.g. alphabetically), the concept of " all columns between column A and column B" is meaningless

Comment: Normalize or write a custom function. What are you using to program GUI?